# How can i add ProGuard to project with dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

I want to add proguard to my application that include alot of dependenciesan and libraries , and my knowledge is to add the following :

```
buildTypes {

debug {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

}
```

My question is should i add proguard to each dependency of them or that will affect them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't exist an answer for all cases, it depends by what is your final goal, which are the dependencies and if you are the owner of the libraries.

In general to minimize problems a good way is to include library and dependencies in the project and then run ProGuard on top of it.

Of course if you are distributing an own library that included proprietary algorithms the best way is to obfuscate the code in the library (and may be Proguard is not the best solution in this case).